# Create circle on svg map

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am facing an issue where I have a map, I have also derived coordinates to plot on the map. However, the circle is not being generated. My code to plot the circle looks like this:

```
g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(cityOrdinates)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (event) {
        return projection(event[1])[0]
    })
    .attr("cy", function (event) {
        console.log(projection(event))
        return projection(event[1])[1]
    })
    .attr("r", function (event) {
        indCityCount = cityDetails.find(({
            city
        }) => city === event[0])
        return radiusScaler(indCityCount.males + indCityCount.females) + 'px';
    })
    .attr("fill", function(event) {
        indCityCount = cityDetails.find(({
            city
        }) => city === event[0])
        if (indCityCount.males == 0) {
            return 'red'
        } else if (indCityCount.females == 0) {
            return 'blue'
        }
        gradient(indCityCount.males, indCityCount.females)
        return 'url(#gradient)'
    })
    .style('opacity', 0.4)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', '0.5px')
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong and would really appreciate some ideas on what could be going wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share at least some of `cityOrdinates`, perhaps the first two points you are trying to draw?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remove `+ 'px'` from the `r` attribute.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle: `r` value must be a number, not a CSS size.